# vercel - python app - run some commands before pip install

Tags: vercel

I'm trying to deploy a flask application that requires `pycairo == 1.23.0` on Vercel. During the installation of the `requirements.txt`, I have the following issue:

```bash
Error: Command failed: pip3.9 install --disable-pip-version-check --target . --upgrade -r /vercel/path0/requirements.txt
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/__init__.pyi -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      copying cairo/py.typed -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/cairo
      running build_ext
      Package cairo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
      Perhaps you should add the directory containing `cairo.pc'
      to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
      No package 'cairo' found
      Command '['pkg-config', '--print-errors', '--exists', 'cairo >= 1.15.10']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
      [end of output]
```

I've found the fix for linux (which is the case on Vercel) which requires to run first:

```bash
sudo apt-get install pkg-config 
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev
```

I've tried to create a `package.json` at the root of the project but the command was not running. Here is my  current `vercel.json` & `package.json` files:

```bash
vercel.json
{
    "builds": [
      {
        "src": "api/app.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python"
      }
    ],
    "routes": [
      {
        "src": "/(.*)",
        "dest": "api/app.py"
      }
    ]
  }
```

```bash
package.json
{
    "scripts": {
          "build": "sudo apt-get install pkg-config libcairo2-dev"
      }
  }
```

I did not find int the documentation something to add those commands prior the installation of the requirements.

Thanks for any clue you may have,

Nicolas

Comment: Hi, I'am running into the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi, unfortunately not yet. If I find something, I'll post it here